# vb.net Process.Start local path

Tags: vb.net, path

So i know in html you can use ../xx/ to open files in the same folder as the code. I want to do the same with Process.Start. This is my attempt at is but it cannot find the file.

```
    Private Sub btn_database_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_database.Click
           Process.Start(".\WindowsApp10\WindowsApp10\WindowsApp10\WindowsApp10\bin\Debug\InventoryManager2.accdb")
End Sub
```

This is the path file I'm trying to open. `C:\Users\Michal\Downloads\WindowsApp10\WindowsApp10\WindowsApp10\WindowsApp10\bin\Debug\InventoryManager2.accdb`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application.StartupPath` will give you the path of the folder the current EXE was run from, so:

```
Process.Start(IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "InventoryManager2.accdb"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what i was looking for!